# Include only rows that contain names specified in list?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe that has multiple columns, and it's ordered by AccountAlias, by which I mean the first column is called "AccountAlias"

| AccountAlias | Stock_1 | Stock_2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Client Name 1 | costbasis | costbasis |
| Client Name 2 | costbasis | costbasis |
| ... | costbasis | costbasis |

This is basically what my dataframe looks like. Now, I want to load a csv file that's just a column with names on it, and then I want to load that csv file into my work. Then I want to filter out all of the clients and their information that are not in my csv file.

The end result should be like so

| AccountAlias | Stock_1 | Stock_2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Client in my list | costbasis | costbasis |
| Client in my list | costbasis | costbasis |
| Client in my list | costbasis | costbasis |

I tried downloading the csv file and converting to a list, and then using

df = df[mylist]

but that is trying to include only the columns with the values in my list, which there are none because those values are contained in my rows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you got `KeyError: 'AccountAlias'` when accessing the column `AccountAlias`, it is possible that your `AccountAlias` is actually in the row index instead of in data columns, like below:

```
                 Stock_1    Stock_2
AccountAlias                       
Client Name 1  costbasis  costbasis
Client Name 2  costbasis  costbasis
```

Note that the label `AccountAlias` in at a line lower than the line containing the column labels `Stock_1`, `Stock_2`.  This is the setting for row index label.

In this case, if you want to filter on the rows in your list `mylist`, you can use:

```
df_out = df.loc[df.index.isin(mylist)]
```

### Demo

**Input**

```
mylist = ['Client Name 1']

# before filtering
print(df)


                 Stock_1    Stock_2
AccountAlias                       
Client Name 1  costbasis  costbasis
Client Name 2  costbasis  costbasis
```

**Output**

```
df_out = df.loc[df.index.isin(mylist)]

print(df_out)


                 Stock_1    Stock_2
AccountAlias                       
Client Name 1  costbasis  costbasis
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `.isin`

```
df = df[df.loc[:, 'AccountAlias'].isin(mylist)]
```

Comment: does your mylist contain other objects than strings?

Comment: For some reason it returns

KeyError: 'AccountAlias'

But I am literally looking at my dataframe and the first column is called AccountAlias.